# Is there a way to toggle Sticky keys on/off programmatically?

Tags: windows, keyboard, accessibility

I want to enable/disable the Windows sticky keys feature from a program. Is there a way to do it by calling a command line script or using vbscript or similar?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Autohotkey. That's why I need a command line solution (like a small bvscript), because Autohotkey can't control this out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Call [SystemParametersInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947(VS.85).aspx) with SPI_SETSTICKYKEYS as first argument.

You will need to use P/Invoke to call the Win32 API function, though, if you use .NET.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. I never used the Winapi, I hope it can be done in a few lines with vbscript and the windows scripting host.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
echo Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 > Script.reg

echo [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\StickyKeys] >> Script.reg
echo "Flags"="127" >> Script.reg
reg Import Script.reg
exit
```